# MS Office 356 Access Sign-in

Tags: ms-access, office365, ms-office, terminal-server

We have installed MS O365 on our Terminal Servers, and because O365 is a cloud service, it always asks for Sing-in so that it could see if user account has a licence.
The thing is we have about 10 accounts that are made only so that the users can only open Access (self-programmed) Programs and work, they do not have or need a licence.
Is it possible to somehow to turn off the Sing-in prompts?

I tried to install MS Access Runtime 2013 , as it is not possible to install 2016 Version.
It did not solve our problem as the users always have to choose which of the two Accesses should they open it, and i dont have option to add the Access programs to Trust Center and they always get the security warning message.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: For anyone that has the same trouble with O365 (Licenses), the solution that Mr. Gustav works, but I have found yet another solution that also seems to work (we also have .mdb programs).

It is possible to make a shortcut from .mdb and in "Properties" under "Target:", at the end of link, to put  /runtime, and the shourtcut will allways start in a Runtime Mode.
The cool thing about it is, you dont have to have Access Runtime installed.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename your `application.accdb` to `.accdr` and it will launch in runtime mode.

Also, see my article:

[Deploy and update a Microsoft Access application with one click](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/33417/Deploy-and-update-a-Microsoft-Access-application-with-one-click.html?preview=X8LitkMCd/Y%3D)

Comment: Thank you very much, that solves the "Open with" problem.
I have read your article, and saved it for later implementation.

However I still have the Trusted Location inconvenience, as I can add the Network Location in Registry-HKCU as Trusted location, but only for the Current User.
In Local Machine the Access\Security is not present (or I just cant find it)

As these Production accounts dont have the rights to open regedit, only Admins can, I can just change it for Admin account.

Do you maybe have some suggestions about that?

Comment: The script in the article solves that. Note please, that the script was originally created for users of Citrix - an extremely offending environment.